# New to SQL - Why is my Insert into trying to insert NULL into primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

What I want to do is insert a range of dates into multiple rows for customerID=1. I have and insert for dbo.Customer(Dates), specifying my that I want to insert a record into the Dates column for my Customer table, right? I am getting error:

> **Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerId', table 'dbo.Customers'**

Sorry if I am way off track here. I have looked at similar threads to find out what I am missing, but I'm not piecing this together. I am thinking it wants to overwrite the existing customer ID as NULL, but I am unsure why exactly since I'm specifying dbo.Customer(Dates) and not the existing customerID for that record.

```
declare @date_Start datetime = '03/01/2011'
declare @date_End datetime = '10/30/2011'
declare @date datetime = @date_Start

while @date <= @date_End
begin
insert into dbo.Customer(Dates) select @date
if DATEPART(dd,@date) = 0
    set @date = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm,1,@date))
else
    set @date = DATEADD(dd,1,@date)
end

select * from dbo.Customer
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a new record into `dbo.Customer` which also has a `NOT NULL` column named `CustomerId`. You don't specify a value for `CustomerId`, so you get the error.

Comment: Hi, please provided your ddl (structure off table and create table definition) i think your customerId wasn't a auto increment and a primary key and it not be null

Comment: I suggest against using a `WHILE` to create a list of dates; they're awfully slow. Use a tally table or a Calendar table. Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b109126abe0315f3cafcaa57b27f3dc0)

Comment: Side note: `DATEPART(dd,@date)` will never return `0` - There's no such date....

Comment: Side note #2: When using date literals you should use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD. The string literals you have here will fail depending on the language or the current dateformat for the connection.

Comment: I think you are confused on how a table works. Your "Dates" column is NOT a collection of values. It is a column with a single value in it. When you insert a new row and do not specify CustomerID it will attempt to insert NULL which your table does not allow.

Comment: Sean Lange is right, It does insert new rows. I was confused and thought the "Dates" column create more date entries instead of just the one field for the one record. I am trying to create multiple records for the same customerId

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is `customerId`, but you are not inserting a value.

My guess is that you declared it as a primary key with something like this:

```
customerId int primary key,
```

You want it to be an `identity` column, so the database assigns a value:

```
customerId int identity(1, 1) primary key
```

Then, you don't need to assign a value into the column when you insert a new row -- the database does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Customer table has a column named CustomerId and which column is NOT Nullable so you have to provide that column value as well. If your column type is Int try the bellow code:

```
declare @date_Start datetime = '03/01/2011'
declare @date_End datetime = '10/30/2011'
declare @date datetime = @date_Start
DECLARE @cusId INT

SET @cusId = 1

while @date <= @date_End
begin
insert into dbo.Customer(CustomerId, Dates) select @cusId, @date
if DATEPART(dd,@date) = 0
    set @date = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm,1,@date))
else
    set @date = DATEADD(dd,1,@date)

    SET @cusId = @cusId + 1;
end

select * from dbo.Customer
```

Comment: That seems to be working to add new rows, but still getting Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Customer__E67E1A240AD36B5C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Customer'.

Could this be resolved by adding an update statement and adding ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" for customerId =1?

Comment: Can you please give me the table structure? with create table script? I can check my side.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the feedback. I think I'm scrapping this and going to go with creating a separate table to JOIN. Not sure why I didn't start doing that before